# Cannot read properties of null in SPA javascript when reading a form in another route

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I have the below single page application, but when I go to the login route, and submit, the event listener for the form is not triggered

And I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
> at login?session%5Bemail%5D=fdf%40gmail.com&session%5Bpassword%5D=dfdf&session%5Bremember_me%5D=0:34:6

**This is the home page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vanilla SPA Router</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <nav id="main-nav" class="sidebar">
                <a href="/" onclick="route()">Home</a>
                <a href="/about" onclick="route()">About</a>
                <a href="/lorem" onclick="route()">Lorem</a>
                <a href="/login" onclick="route()">login</a>

            </nav>
            <div id="main-page"></div>
        </div>



<script>
  const form = document.querySelector("#userinfo");
  console.log("I'm here 1");
async function sendData() {
  console.log("I'm here 2");
  const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
    outputElement.innerHTML = "change success";

}
// Take over form submission
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  sendData();
});
</script>

        <script src="js/router.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is the login page**

```
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
        
          <form id="userinfo">
  
              <label for="session_email">Email</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="session[email]" id="session_email" />
  
              <label for="session_password">Password</label>
              <a href="/password_resets/new">(forgot password)</a>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="session[password]" id="session_password" />
  
              <label class="checkbox inline" for="session_remember_me">
                  <input name="session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" autocomplete="off" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="session[remember_me]" id="session_remember_me" />
                  <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
          <p>New user? <a href="/signup">sign up now!</a></p>
      </div>
      <div id="output" style="color:black">
        before change
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
const route = (event) => {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
    handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
    404: "/pages/404.html",
    "/": "/pages/index.html",
    "/about": "/pages/about.html",
    "/lorem": "/pages/lorem.html",
    "/login": "/pages/login.html",

};

const handleLocation = async () => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    const route = routes[path] || routes[404];
    const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
    document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to add an event listener to the form element which hasn't been initialized yet, because you are still on the homepage. And the form element is on the login page.

Move the logic to take over form submission into the login page.

Or write some logic to run it only after the Login page has loaded